# Can a bounty be somehow divided equally among two answers?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Assuming two answers are equally good can the mods somehow divide the bounty points among those answers. I don't wish to be unfair to the other equally good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't divide a bounty - you must award it to one post.

Bounties are described in full here:
https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: I can't - I know, but I thought moderators could?

Comment: @user462608 I think it might be possible for SE employees to do something about bounties under exceptional circumstances, but I checked questions that both have bounties pending, and bounties that have been actively awarded, and I see no special moderator tool that would allow them to be manually split.  Personally, if I found two answers equally good, I'd award the bounty to the one with the lower vote total. If the vote totals were the same, I'd award the bounty to the user with the lower reputation.

Comment: @Beofett Thanks for following up. Also, I see tags with synonyms like - newborn and newborns. Do these together make sense?

Comment: @user462608 Tags can be made synonyms when its decided that there is no practical difference between them. In this case, [tag:newborn] is the main tag, and [tag:newborns] is its synonym. By doing this, if someone accidentally types "newborns" for the tag, it automatically changes to "newborn" so we don't wind up with duplicate tags. You can't add both to the same question, because essentially they're the same.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to split bounties.  Answering a question with a bounty is a bit of a crap shoot.  Sometimes an answer will win the bounty because nobody else tried.  And sometimes several people will answer and the person offering the bounty has a tough choice.  You could argue that the [gambling instinct](http://www.economist.com/node/16507720) played a large role in attracting those answers.

Now if you *really* like both answers, you could offer a second bounty (which will be larger) to reward the second answer after you've awarded the first.  Of course, that will also cost more reputation, which you might not be willing to spend.  Or, if you asked the question, you could award the bounty to one and accept the other.

But if you got one good answer (much less several) you've come out ahead, the site has more great content, and the bounty system worked as designed.

See also: [Accept Multiple Answers or Split Bounty among Several Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/1438).